# Restrict core usages PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, multicore

I have this program that I've written in PyCharm. This program should be running for a week or so, and it is very processor-needy. So when I run it I pretty much have no use of my notebook, as it becomes very laggy.

Is there a way to somehow tell PyCharm to use first three of my cores and leave one for other programms so they can operate normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go into task manager
2. Find the running task (it probably won't be the main pycharm window)
3. Right click and select "go to details"
4. Right click on the details and click "set affinity"
5. Select whatever cores you wish the program to use

Alternatively you can use the "set priority" sub-menu and set it to "below normal". All other processes are normal priority by default, so it shouldn't interfere with anything, but still use any other available processing power. You can do the same thing with long installations or automatic windows updates so they don't slow you down.

I should also note that both of these selections will be reset upon restarting the program. Additionally, if you are using windows 7, you don't need to "go to details". Everything will appear in the context menu for the process.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in pycharm.

Comment: Good answer! I will accept it, because it can help some users, but in my case I run a programm, that `subprocess.call`s external program 100 000 times, so processes spawn and I cannot restrict some one process. 

Also, that programm finished, so it's not really actual right now :)